# How to make a View's width to be minimum of {"match_parent", "300dp"}

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `View` inside `RelativeLayout` and I want its width to be `match_parent`, but not greater than `300dp`.

Using these makes it always `match_parent`:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:maxWidth="300dp"
```

And using these makes it always the smallest size possible:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:maxWidth="300dp"
```

**One possible solution**: I can can use `sw300dp` variant for layout; but I don't like the duplication involved in this approach, because lots of other properties and views would be alike and duplicated across two layout files.

Comment: i would suggest you to get Screen width dynamically & after it set width according to you.

Comment: That's the last resort. I was hoping for this simple task, there would be a one-liner xml solution!

Comment: why dont you put RelativeLayout width to : 300dp.

Comment: 300 is just a random number I wrote here. Let's say the real number is 500dp. What happens in a device with screen width 400dp?

Comment: you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html